All function with lazy evaluation
I'm new to Mathematica so I will write my requirements as a pseudocode.
I have a list of Hold instances.
I need to traverse a list and release the elements one by one. If False is returned, I need to return False.
If all elements have returned True I return True.
It is like all function, but it is important not to process elements ahead.
How to implement it?

You want to use AllTrue for this

"it is like all function" Er... what language?

@xzczd  most likely they mean Matlab as in this help page all(A) tests along the first array dimension of A whose size does not equal 1, and determines if the elements are all nonzero or logical 1 (true). In practice, all is a natural extension of the logical

Taking a hint from a comment, we can use AllTrue, since it will only evaluate elements up until one of them is False.
For instance, consider
list = Table[With[{n = n}, Hold[n + n]], {n, 1, 5}]
(* {Hold[1 + 1], Hold[2 + 2], Hold[3 + 3], Hold[4 + 4], Hold[5 + 5]} *)

Then, suppose the condition is that the expression is smaller than 4. Using AllTrue,  we can do
AllTrue[list, ReleaseHold[#] < 4 &]

which returns False, and by Traceing the evaluation, we can see that doesn't evaluate any of the rest of the elements in the list:
{
 {list, {Hold[1+1],Hold[2+2],Hold[3+3],Hold[4+4],Hold[5+5]}},
 AllTrue[{Hold[1+1],Hold[2+2],Hold[3+3],Hold[4+4],Hold[5+5]},ReleaseHold[#1]<4&],
 {(ReleaseHold[#1] < 4 &)[Hold[1+1]], ReleaseHold[Hold[1+1]] < 4, 
 {ReleaseHold[Hold[1+1]], 1+1, 2}, 2<4, True},
 {(ReleaseHold[#1] < 4 &)[Hold[2+2]], ReleaseHold[Hold[2+2]] < 4, 
 {ReleaseHold[Hold[2+2]], 2+2, 4}, 4<4, False},
 False
}


+1.  We could also use a single wrapping Hold and forgo ReleaseHold, e.g. AllTrue[Hold[1+1,2+2,3+3,4+4,5+5],#<4&]
